# Stopping a loop in R when NA referenced

Tags: r

I'm an inexperienced R programmer, trying to make a piece of code I have written work. This is probably an elemental problem. I want this code to check one value against its predecessor in a vector, and if it is greater than a certain threshold value, to return which element on that vector satisfies this criterion. Once it has found one case, I'd like it to stop.

At present my code half-functions as I'd like it to, but it goes through the whole vector and once it reaches the end it checks a[i+1] which is NA and gives me an error message.

```
testdata<-c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.45,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0)

MLD<-function(a,...){
  x<-NULL
  y<-NULL
  for(i in seq(along=a)){
    if(a[i+1]>=a[i]+0.125)
    {x=c(x,a[i+1]); y=which(a==x); print(y)}
  }
}


try(MLD(testdata),silent=TRUE) # code finds right element
MLD(testdata) # but continues looking until it runs out of data
```

I know I need a `break()` or a `stop()` somewhere but I can't seem to work it out, I hope you can help me.

Comment: csgillespie's answer is the way to go, but for other newbs wondering about loops: since you are comparing `a[i+1]` to `a[i]`, you need to constrain the loop counter.  One easy way is `for(i in 1:(length(a)-1))` .

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code to:

```
which(diff(testdata) > 0.125) + 1
```

Which you could put in a function:

```
MLD = function(a) which(diff(a) > 0.125) + 1
```